# Embedded files not detected at single macro run

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, object-detection

The idea of the script to convert embedded files into its images and paste them on the embedded files and then delete the embedded files(code Below). This is done in vba powerpoint. A problem is occuring when I have embedded equations and embedded images in a slide. The script when it runs first detects 2 out of 3 embedded equations and 1 out of 3 embedded images in a slide and converts them into their images. Running the script second times it detects the one equation which is left and then when I run the script third time it detects the remaining image. So 6 embedded items are detected in script runs 3 times. Any idea where the the problem is.

```
enter code here

 Sub ConvertAllShapesToPic()
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim k
k = 0
With ActivePresentation
    z = .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
    MsgBox z, vbDefaultButton1, "Total Slides"
End With


For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
          For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        Select Case oSh.Type
            Case msoChart, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
                ConvertShapeToPic oSh
                k = 1
            Case Else

        End Select
    Next
Next

If k = 1 Then
MsgBox "Embedded files replaced by their Images", vbDefaultButton1
Else
MsgBox "Embedded files already replaced by their Images", vbDefaultButton1
End If

End Sub

Sub ConvertShapeToPic(ByRef oSh As Shape)
Dim oNewSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim y

Set oSl = oSh.Parent
oSh.Copy
Set oNewSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

With oNewSh
    .Left = oSh.Left
    .Top = oSh.Top

    Do
        .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
    Loop Until .ZOrderPosition = .ZOrderPosition
End With

For y = oSl.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
    If oSh Is oSl.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(y).Shape Then
    oSl.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(y).Shape = oNewSh
    End If
Next y

oSh.Delete

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
      For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
    Select Case oSh.Type
        Case msoChart, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
            ConvertShapeToPic oSh
            k = 1
        Case Else

    End Select
Next
```

With this:

```
  ' Add Dim x as Long to the top of the routine
  For x = oSl.Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
  Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(x)
Select Case oSh.Type
    Case msoChart, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
        ConvertShapeToPic oSh
        k = 1
    Case Else

End Select
```

Next

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfect (y)

Comment: You're very welcome; please consider editing your original question to include the (now) working code and marking it as answered so other people can find it more easily later.  Thanks!

Comment: There's a tick next to the answer you want to accept (think it's greyed out) - could you tick it to show the accepted answer please. :)